# Last updated date in PHP of current document

Tags: php

How can I display the last time the current document was updated in PHP?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If by "current document", you mean "script that is currently being executed", you can use something like this :

```
$timestamp = filemtime(__FILE__);
$date = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', $timestamp);
var_dump($date);
```

And the output is like :

```
string '2009-08-27 20:17:54' (length=19)
```

Which is the date and time it is right now in France ;-)

See [`filemtime`](http://php.net/filemtime) to get the last modification date of a file, and [date](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) and it's formatting options to convert the timestamp returned by `filemtime` to something a human-being can understand.

Comment: Ergh! Indeed I did forgot that one (I've just corrected it) ; thanks for the comment!

Comment: I tried this and the output I get is:  
string(19) "2009-08-27 18:39:01" 
What am I doing wrong?  Sorry, new to PHP.

Comment: What time is it ? ^^ Is the date not correct, considering your file ?

Comment: No, the time isn't correct.  It's about 6 hours ahead.  Also, what is the "string(19)" for?

Comment: the string(19) says $date is a string, 19 characters long ; var_dump is a function used to get debugging informations from variables -- you wouldn't use it to display the date on your real website, of course, when you are done developping. ;; 6 hours ahead is strange... maybe your php.ini contains a not-well-configured "date.timezone" directive ? Else, try setting the right timezone with http://php.net/manual/en/function.date-default-timezone-set.php at the beginning of your script

Comment: Well, I got the time working for now.  I don't necessarily need it, just the date.  But the "string(19)" is still before the timestamp.  Why is this?

Comment: OK about the date/time ;; about "string(19)", if you don't want that debugging information, don't use a debugging function like var_dump : use http://php.net/echo (the normal output construct) for instance.

Comment: Thank you, sorry for being a noob haha.

Answer (score 3):

```
filemtime(); // file modified time
```

Example from PHP.net,

```
<?php
  // outputs e.g.  somefile.txt was last modified: December 29 2002 22:16:23.
  $file= 'somefile.txt';
  if (file_exists($file)) {
    echo "$file was last modified: " . date ("F d Y H:i:s.", filemtime($file));
  }
?>
```